# Home network with loops due to WiFi, precautions needed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a relatively large area in the house that needs to be covered by WiFi. The range of a single access point will most probably not be sufficient as it is built from massive concrete with steel enforcements. Thus, I installed multiple access points all over the place to get sufficient coverage.

I tried to sketch the logical/topological structure of the network in question here:

[image: Network structure]

Obviously, the pure cable-based connections are no problem. All the access points are using the same SSID to allow for fast switching without change of IP or the like.
This has however the effect that when the access points are close enough (depending on the local possibilities for setup), they can receive their partners' packets.

As a result, these wireless connections can be seen as additional connections (from the perspective of the network topology) that can cause loops in the topology. Loops in an Ethernet network is not the best idea, as far as I understand. Here STP (Spanning Tree Protocol) comes into play. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/18079) STP is a hassle and should be avoided when possible in small installations.

Now I have a few questions:

1. Are *normal* switches/access points (customer devices) able to cope with such a situation?
2. Is it necessary to handle this situation in a dedicated way?
3. From time to time, I have huge problems with the WiFi network. Within the network, I get latencies (measured with ping) of up to 5000ms. This is not always the case (sporadic behavior). Could this be caused by such a *weak*, unstable connection?

Comment: Are you using the same channel for all APs? Ideally the channels for each AP should be different and non-overlapping (1, 6, 11).

Comment: I use range extenders.  They are cheap and work well (at least for me).  I use the NETGEAR Wi-Fi Range Extender EX2700 but that is only because it was cheap (under 20 USD).  I doubt that brand matters much.  My son uses the extender for wifi gaming and he is a stickler about latency.

Comment: @senorcmasmas Wifi extenders are a bad technology that, at minimum, reduce the available bandwidth.

Comment: @davidgo , say what you want, they solved the issue for me in my household and I still pull well over 100 megabit through the extender and on my direct network.   Its fast enough for me and might also be fast enough for the OP.  "Wifi extenders are a bad technology" is based on what?  Perhaps in some scenarios, but for me it solved the problem 100%.  How could 100% solved be "bad technology" for me?

Comment: @SenorCmasMas I'm glad you have a solution that works for you, but they double the bandwidth consumed for each packet and also make roaming more painful.  https://www.zirkelwireless.com/wifi_extenders_dont_work/ concurs with my thoughts on the matter, save that I prefer to use ethernet between AP's if thats possible, and would look to Ethernet over Powerline as well before going the mesh route.

Comment: @harrymc no, I distributed the channels as far as I know as much as possible. There are two more WiFis with range, so I must be a bit more careful than just (1 6 11).

Comment: Regarding the range extenders: They will not work for me as the locations will not really allow them to be placed accordingly (within sufficient range). Also, I will have to make multiple hops in order to cover the complete house

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This has however the effect that when the access points are close enough (depending on the local possibilities for setup), they can receive their partners' packets.
>
> As a result, these wireless connections can be seen as additional connections (from the perspective of the network topology) that can cause loops in the topology

No, they don't cause loops, because the real link-layer header<sup>1</sup> of Wi-Fi frames [has a flag bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11_Frame_Types#ToDS_and_FromDS) that indicates whether the frame is from AP to client, or from client to AP. So even if the APs are all on the same channel (which they *shouldn't* be, if they are indeed close enough to hear each other) there won't be a loop because they'll just ignore all frames with the "From DS" flag.

Additionally, all Wi-Fi frames from clients are addressed to a specific BSSID. Under the hood, they have *two* destination MAC addresses – the "final" destination like in Ethernet, and the BSSID of the AP that the client is currently associated with.

(Similarly, frames from APs to clients are interpreted as having two *source* MAC addresses – the original source and the transmitting BSSID.) Note that this is not the same as the *ESSID* which is the textual "network name" – the BSSID is the specific AP's MAC address.

This also means that roaming is done explicitly in Wi-Fi – even if the client is in range of several APs, it will only send frames to only one of them, until it decides to disassociate from it and associate with another.

---

<sup>1</sup> Standard packet captures of a Wi-Fi interface will only show you an *emulated* Ethernet header (which is done by design; 802.11 is meant to provide an 802.2-compatible link layer). If you capture packets in [monitor mode](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Wi-Fi) then you will see the real 802.11 header, as in [these examples](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#Wifi_.2F_Wireless_LAN_captures_.2F_802.11).